# Cannot find module 'node-sass' while buil Angular app

Tags: angular

my global ng version is 1.6.1 and local ng-cli version is 1.6.1 so first warning then i got error,

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
```

so anyone can help me ?

Comment: Can you show how are you importing it in your app.component.scss?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `node-sass` has not been fetched on your desktop when you initiated your angular environment. This probably happened when you launched `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

If you are working in an enterprise context, using

- a web proxy
- a local repository manager (say Nexus) in which packages are first proxified then downloaded to your desktop

then you may encounter this issue.

**Explanation:**

`node-sass` uses compiled `C` libs that are stored in Github. Your local repository manager (a.k.a. Nexus) should not be able to handle such a dependency.

**Sollution:**

If you are allowed to get out of your enterprise through the proxy, then you should configure the proxy in your `.npmrc` file (it should not be difficult to find a tuto that explains how). Then relaunch `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

If you are **not** allowed to get out of your enterprise through the web proxy, then your only sollution is to ask your Software Factory manager to package this `npm` module for you, including the `C` lib dependency.

Note that the situation that i just describe is not uncommon with `npm` packages.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the **node_modules directory** and **re-installing** the node modules.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing `node-sass` in your project. Try installing it through `npm i node-sass -D` and rerun again.